# Instant property precision lost on update

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, npgsql, nodatime

I have a table backed by PostgreSQL with NPGSQL driver that is represented by a class:

```
class table1 {
  string Id { get; set; }
  Instant CreatedAt { get; set; }
  int State { get; set; }
  Instant UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

The primary key is defined as composite of Id and CreatedAt:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<table1>()
    .HasKey(t => new { t.CreatedAt, t.Id });
```

The problem happens when I do:

```
var row = db.table1.First();
row.State = 5;
row.UpdatedAt = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.UtcNow);
db.SaveChanges();
```

The result is DbUpdateConcurrencyException because the UPDATE truncates the Instant to this:

```
  UPDATE "table1" SET "State" = 5, "UpdatedAt" = '2019-01-08T15:25:09Z'
  WHERE "CreatedAt" = '2018-12-07T15:25:09Z' AND "Id" = 'ID000001';
```

The precision to microseconds has been completely lost in the UPDATE and the result is:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database
>   operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s).
>   Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Well, what does your UpdateAp column looks like in your DB? If you tell me it's a regular DateTime column then it's no wonder why it doesn't work. DateTime does not take microseconds

Comment: It is of course "timestamp with time zone" and the value looks like '2018-12-07 15:25:09.647525'

Answer (score 1):

So I found it. I needed to provide a ColumnType in DBContext OnModelCreating() method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<table1>().Property(p => p.CreatedAt)
    .HasColumnType("timestamp with time zone");
```